# How to convert timespan to decimal?

Tags: c#, .net, decimal, timespan

I have a value of exactly `1.08:43:23` in my textbox, which is equal to 1d, 08:43:23. I wanted to convert the value to decimal for me to multiply it by another decimal value, however when I used `Convert.ToDecimal` it returns the error

> Input string is not a valid format

Is `Convert.ToDecimal` not appropriate for this kind of conversion ? Is there a way to create a decimal value from such input?

Comment: You can use TotalSeconds property of timespan

Comment: Which decimal do you think corresponds to 1d 08:43:32? Are you converting the string to decimal, or a timespan object to decimal?

Comment: What do you hope to gain by multiplying a length of time with another?

Comment: Am working with some kind of payroll system, I wanted to get the earning based on timespan

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Is `Convert.ToDecimal` is not appropriate for this kind of conversion ?

No. You need to parse it to `TimeSpan` first (with a culture that has `:` as a [`TimeSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.timeseparator.aspx) of course.). Then you can get which duration type do you want as a `double` from it.

```
var ts = TimeSpan.Parse("1.08:43:23", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[image]

Then you can use [`TotalXXX` properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan_properties.aspx) which type duration do you want as a `double` (seconds, milliseconds etc.).

Comment: This works too, thank you so much sir. Though has the same idea as above, I'll commend yah still, mind if I ask you a question ?

Comment: @SuperPruuylan Sure, that's what comment section are for.

Comment: what compiler are you using sir ?

Comment: @SuperPruuylan Visual Studio Ultimate 2012. But I think you try to ask: "What theme are you using?" It is default Dark theme in VS which you can change it on `Tools -> Change Color Theme -> Dark`

Comment: Also, the information in the picture can be seen during debugging. You need to set a breakpoint on the line you're interested in, and then hover over a variable to see values of all its fields and properties.

Comment: Am using Visual Studio Enterprise 2012, am using dark theme too but my fonts appears blue. lol I just loved your compiler, how it look likes

Answer (score 3):

This will give u total number of ticks ..

```
decimal dec = Convert.ToDecimal(TimeSpan.Parse("11:30").Ticks);
```

Comment: This works, thank you so much sir, can't tag "answered" yet. I'll tag it later, thank you so much, sir