# TimeSpan FromHours With Decimal

Tags: c#

Is it possible to use the `TimeSpan.FromHours` with values of type `decimal`? I need it to be as precise as possible. I know I could cast it to double but that will make the result inaccurate. I was thinking about writing an overloaded extension method but I am not sure how to do that.

**Edit**
A little background information. The database is using `decimal` as the type which is `decimal` in C#. If I am using `double`, I would have to use `float` in the database which is known to be bad.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33296750/how-to-convert-timespan-to-decimal ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiple the `decimal` value by the number of ticks per hour (`TimeSpan.TicksPerHour`).

Cast the result to `long`, and then use `TimeSpan.FromTicks`.

The risks of this are:

- You have a `decimal` representing a number of hours that can't be represented in a `TimeSpan`
- You have a `decimal` which requires sub-tick precision

In neither case can you actually end up with a `TimeSpan` which accurately represents your value - so you'd need to look for an alternative type. (If you want to use my [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org) library, the `Duration` type has a precision of nanoseconds and a range of just under 46,000 years - both positive and negative. But you'd really need to move to Noda Time everywhere.)

Comment: Thanks for the through answer. I will definitely take a look at your library!

Answer (score 0):

A `System.TimeSpan` is backed by `long` which still would not hold enough precision for the full width of a `decimal`. If you need that precision, I'd suggest writing your own `TimeSpan`.